# How to map /dev/sg2 to /dev/sdb

Tags: centos, scsi

My server has been added a new hard disk. But the system does not recognize the hard disk.

fdisk result:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 73.3 GB, 73283928064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8909 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8f035cdf

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26        1046     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            1046        8910    63168512   83  Linux
```

lsscsi result:

```
# lsscsi -x

[0:0:0:0x0000]              disk    ServeRA  8k-l Volume      V1.0  /dev/sda
[0:1:0:0x0000]              disk    FUJITSU  MAX3073RC        D207  -
[0:1:1:0x0000]              disk    SEAGATE  ST4000NM0023     0006  -
[0:3:0:0x0000]              enclosu IBM      SAS SES-2 DEVICE 1.10  -
[1:0:0:0x0000]              cd/dvd  MATSHITA UJDA780 DVD/CDRW CA22  /dev/sr0
```

smartctl result:

```
# smartctl -d scsi --all /dev/sg2 -H

smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST4000NM0023
Revision:             0006
User Capacity:        4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c500987fbe97
Serial number:        S1Z2HY330000K705UAQG
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
Local Time is:        Thu Feb  9 15:39:38 2017 CST
Device supports SMART and is Enabled
Temperature Warning Enabled
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     32 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        60 C
Manufactured in week 35 of year 2016
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  88
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  102
Elements in grown defect list: 0
Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 9916
  Blocks received from initiator = 0
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 999872
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 10
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0
Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 389.68
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 52

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:       7013        0         0      7013          0          0.004           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0          0.143           0
verify:     2906        0         0      2906          0          0.001           0

Non-medium error count:       13

[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
No self-tests have been logged
Long (extended) Self Test duration: 32700 seconds [545.0 minutes]
```

udevadm info:

```
# udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sg2)

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1/0:1:1:0/scsi_generic/sg2':
    KERNEL=="sg2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_generic"
    DRIVER==""

device 0x7f357e2fd290 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1/0:1:1:0'
udevadm[16020]: device 0x7f357e2fd290 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1/0:1:1:0'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1/0:1:1:0':
    KERNELS=="0:1:1:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="SEAGATE "
    ATTRS{model}=="ST4000NM0023    "
    ATTRS{rev}=="0006"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="0"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0xe"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0xe"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{modalias}=="scsi:t-0x00"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{queue_ramp_up_period}=="120000"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{level}=="Hidden"

device 0x7f357e2fe010 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1'
udevadm[16020]: device 0x7f357e2fe010 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:1:1':
    KERNELS=="target0:1:1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

device 0x7f357e2fe340 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0'
udevadm[16020]: device 0x7f357e2fe340 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/host0':
    KERNELS=="host0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

device 0x7f357e2fe650 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0'
udevadm[16020]: device 0x7f357e2fe650 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:02:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="aacraid"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x9005"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x0286"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1014"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x9580"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x010400"
    ATTRS{irq}=="17"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{modalias}=="pci:v00009005d00000286sv00001014sd00009580bc01sc04i00"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""

device 0x7f357e2ff6e0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0'
udevadm[16020]: device 0x7f357e2ff6e0 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:07.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x25e7"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0000"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{irq}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{modalias}=="pci:v00008086d000025E7sv00000000sd00000000bc06sc04i00"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"

device 0x7f357e2ff990 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00'
udevadm[16020]: device 0x7f357e2ff990 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00'
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

ls result:

```
# ll /dev/disk/by-id/

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 2017-02-08 17:33 scsi-SServeRA_8k-l_Volume_A45B4638 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2017-02-08 17:33 scsi-SServeRA_8k-l_Volume_A45B4638-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2017-02-08 17:33 scsi-SServeRA_8k-l_Volume_A45B4638-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2017-02-08 17:33 scsi-SServeRA_8k-l_Volume_A45B4638-part3 -> ../../sda3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 120 2017-01-25 10:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 100 2017-01-25 10:49 ..
```

Where is /dev/sdb, or how to make it work ?
Thanks.

Comment: What type of disk is that disk? You could try a 
**echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan** and then try again the fdisk

Comment: This could be a BIOS issue due to the large hard disk.  Check your motherboard vendor's site for updated BIOS.  Failing that, it could be too old a kernel?  But, I'd check BIOS first.

Comment: The BIOS has not been tested.
The hard disk is not installed on host1 and it is installed on host0